# move 2 columns to another column in an update query using sql and php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a code in php which updates a row in ms sql. Shown below

```
LONG    | LAT |OLD LONG | OLD LAT | PLATENO

121.666 | 35.222 |   |     | AA-1982
```

now if i insert another data which is LONG = 121.777
 and LAT = 35.333 with the same plate no, it will not insert but instead update the record above to like this

```
LONG |  LAT |   OLDLONG |   OLDLAT |    PLATENO

121.777 | 35.333 |  121.666 |   35.222 |    AA-1982
```

if you notice I move the lat long to OLD LAT AND OLD LONG

but if I insert another data which do not have the same plateno then it will look like this

```
LONG |  LAT |   OLDLONG |   OLDLAT |    PLATENO

121.666 |   35.222 |     |       | AA-1982

121.666 |   35.222 |     |       | BB-1234
```

and this is my code

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE TblCurrenttemp
SET LAT = '$finlat', oldlat = (SELECT lat FROM TblCurrenttemp AS LAT1 WHERE (plateno = '$pltefin')),
    LONG = '$finlong', oldlong = (SELECT long FROM TblCurrenttemp AS LONG1 WHERE (plateno = '$pltefin'))
    WHERE  (plateno = '$pltefin')";
$res1 = mssql_query($sql1) or print("Error " . mssql_get_last_message());
```

Im new to php so sorry if im having some trouble doing it right. I also copied some codes from other posts here so please be patient with me.

Comment: and what was the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE TblCurrenttemp
SET oldlat = LAT,
oldlong = LONG,
LAT = '$finlat', 
LONG = '$finlong'
WHERE  (plateno = '$pltefin')";
$res1 = mssql_query($sql1) or print("Error " . mssql_get_last_message());
```